# Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'KeyPath<[PostDTO], [Post]>' that does not accept a closure

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, combine

I have the following provider class which returns an API response as a Publisher of PostDTO:

```
func getUserPosts(userID: String) -> AnyPublisher<[PostDTO], NetworkErrors> {
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=\(userID)")
            return AF.request(url!,method: .get)
                         .publishDecodable(type: [PostDTO].self)
                         .value()
                         .mapError { _ in NetworkErrors.decoderError }
                         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

I am now trying to map the array PostDTO object to array of Post like the following in my interactor class:

```
func getUserPosts(userID: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Post], NetworkErrors> {
    postListRemoteProvider.getUserPosts(userID: userID).map {
        Post(id: $0.id, title: $0.title, detail: $0.body, isFavorite: false)
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But I am getting the following error when I try to map the PostDTO to Post in above function:

> Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'KeyPath<[PostDTO],
> [Post]>' that does not accept a closure

Can someone please help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUserPosts` returns a publisher that outputs *arrays* (`[PostDTO]` means `Array<PostDTO>`). When you `map` it, the `$0` parameter is a `[PostDTO]`, not a `PostDTO`. There are no `id` or `title` properties on an array.

What you meant to do is to turn `$0`, which is a `[PostDTO]`, into a `[Post]`. That is transforming one array to another array - you should use `map` on `$0` again.

```
postListRemoteProvider.getUserPosts(userID: userID).map { postDtoArray in
    postDtoArray.map {
        Post(id: $0.id, title: $0.title, detail: $0.body, isFavorite: false)
    }
}.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```